# Elevator stop, other approach

Tags: probability

There is a $10$-floor building, $10$ people get in the elevator in the ground floor and each gets off at one of the floors randomly and independently. What is the probability that the elevator stops at floor $5$?

$$1 - (9/10)^{10}$$

I understand the approach of using the probability that no one gets out on the $3$rd floor, which is $(9/10)^{10}$.

But, my question is how do I approach this problem using the probability that people gets out on the $3$rd floor?
I thought if one person chooses the $5$th floor the probability is $1/10$, and if $2$ people choose the $5$th floor then the probability is $1/9$, and so on. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an alternative way to solve this, although it's more difficult than [the method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563009/a-simple-probability-of-the-elevators-stop/563022#563022) you mentioned.

Start by considering the case where there are 2 floors and 2 people.  The probability of at least one person exiting on our chosen floor, say floor 2, is
$$P(\geq\text{1 person on floor; 2 people and 2 floors}) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{3}{4}$$
To see where this came from, we first consider where person 1 gets off.  There is a $1/2$ chance the person will exit on our chosen floor, so we add that to our probability.  In the event that she doesn't get off on floor 2 (an event with probability $1/2$), we consider the other person.  Person 2 has a $1/2$ probability of exiting on floor 2, so we multiply that by the probability that the second person even matters (ie. the probability of the first person *not* getting off on floor 2).

For 3 people and 3 floors, we'd have
$$P(\geq\text{1 person on floor; 3 people and 3 floors}) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right) = \frac{19}{27}$$
since there's a $1/3$ chance of the first person getting off on our chosen floor, and a $2/3$ probability that they don't and that we have to look at the second person.  The same logic is applied to the second person and so on.

For 4 people and 4 floors, we'd have
\begin{align}P(\geq\text{1 person on floor; 4 people and 4 floors}) &= \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)\right) \\
 &= \frac{175}{256}\end{align}

For $N$ people and $N$ floors, we'd have
\begin{align}&P(\geq\text{1 person on floor; N people and N floors}) \\ =& \frac{1}{N} + \frac{N-1}{N}\left(\frac{1}{N}+\frac{N-1}{N}\left(\;\;\;\;\left.\ldots+\frac{N-1}{N}\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)\right)\right)\ldots\right)
\end{align}
where the pattern continues until there are $N$ of the fractions $1/N$ present in the expression.

By multiplying this out, we have
\begin{align} P =& \frac{1}{N}+\frac{\left(N-1\right)}{N^2}+\frac{\left(N-1\right)^2}{N^3}+\ldots+\frac{\left(N-1\right)^{N-1}}{N^N} \\
=& \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{N} \left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^k
\end{align}
and using the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series, ie
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a r^k = \frac{a\left(1-r^n\right)}{1-r}$$
we get, 
\begin{align}P =& \frac{\left(\frac{1}{N}\right) \left(1-\left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^N\right)}{1-\left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)} \\
=& 1 - \left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^N
\end{align}
which is the same expression as the one given by the more [simple method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563009/a-simple-probability-of-the-elevators-stop/563022#563022).

Comment: OK, I LOVE U. IF THIS IS RIGHT, I'LL BE SO GLAD. latest tomorrow. THANKS AGAIN

Comment: ok this made sense to me. Thank you very much again. Wish you the best.

Comment: just one quick question... how did u simply at the end? Can you show me a step by step simplification? I'm having trouble simplifying it

Comment: @user59768, good catch! I was being sloppy. I didn't actually know how to prove it, I just conjectured it because I knew it should be the same as the answer for the alternative method. Anyway, I figured it out and edited my answer.

Comment: Quick question: For example, for 2 people and 2 floors, how come we used the probability that the person doesn't get off times the probability that the second person gets off. Shouldn't there be two cases, 1. one person gets off 2. two people gets off. Why does the probability of the first person not getting off play a role in calculating the probability the second person gets off? Th

Comment: basically, why do we consider the second person when the first person doesn't get off? this part did not make sense to me

Comment: For 2 floors and 2 people, there are three ways that at least 1 person gets off on floor 2.  The first 2 ways are person A gets off, and person B either gets off or doesn't.  The combined probability of these two events is 1/2 (the first term in the first equation of answer).  The last option is person A doesn't get off (P=1/2), and person B does (P=1/2).  You multiply the probabilities: (1/2)*(1/2) which is the second term of the expression.

Comment: "The combined probability of these two events is 1/2 " can you provide an explicit explanation? Is this how you interpret it - Person A has a 1/2 chance of getting off and person b can either get off or not, which is 1, and that multiplied together is 1/2. For the last option, shouldn't it be that person A doesn't get off, and person B (gets off or doesn't depending on the first case?) why can we assume/know that person B does get off?

Comment: For the first part, yes, that's how I was interpreting it.  For the second part (where person A doesn't get off), I'm only interested in the case where person B does get off since we're talking about the probability of at least 1 person exiting on floor 2.  So, we ignore the last possible scenario where no one exits on floor 2 (probability 1/4).

Comment: Thanks. Why does binomial distribution work? As well, if the question was the probability that the elevator stops at a floor, I would understand it to be what we wrote 1-(9/10)^10. However, the probability that the elevator stops at exactly floor 3, wouldn't I do the reasoning for every other floor? that it has a probability of stopping at floor 4, 5, and so on too, which are all 65.13%. How doe that make sense? doesn't this value seem too high?